# How to parse through a string in perl to extract certain value?

Tags: regex, perl

I have following string

```
> show box detail
   2 boxes:
1) Box ID: 1
   IP:                  127.0.0.1
   Interface:           1/1
   Priority:            31
2) Box ID: 2
   IP:                  192.68.1.1
   Interface:           1/2
   Priority:            31
```

How to get BOX ID from above string in perl? 
The number of boxes here can vary . So based on the number of boxes "n", how to extract box Ids if the show box detail can go upto n nodes in the same format ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my @ids = $string =~ /Box ID: ([0-9]+)/g;
```

More restrictive:

```
my @ids = $string =~ /^[0-9]+\) Box ID: ([0-9]+)$/mg;
```

Comment: The match operator in list context returns all captured strings. If /g is used, this means all captured string from all iterations. In short: it returns all the ids.